# color tree Node according to database C# code

Tags: c#, css, treeview, treenode

I'm writing asp.net code(web form ) with treeVeiw  tags Here I'm added tage treeVeiw with ParentNodeStyle ,leafNodestyle,images ,Hovernodestyle  like following code :

```
   <asp:TreeView runat="server" ID="TreeView1" CssClass="tbl"     
OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None"     
BorderWidth="2px" CollapseImageToolTip="Collapse {0}" 
CollapseImageUrl="~/InternalKuah/WebApplication1/WebApplication1/images/menuDown.png" 
ExpandImageUrl="~/InternalKuah/WebApplication1/WebApplication1/images/menuUp.png" Font- 
Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCCCCC" NodeWrap="True" Font-Size="Larger" 
NoExpandImageUrl="~/InternalKuah/WebApplication1/WebApplication1/images/MenuUp.png" 
OnTreeNodeExpanded="TreeView1_TreeNodeExpanded1">
<LeafNodeStyle  ChildNodesPadding="5px" 
 Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Bahnschrift" Font-Size="Large"
  BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Outset" 
ForeColor="Black"
BackColor="AliceBlue"  NodeSpacing="2px"  />
                   
<ParentNodeStyle BackColor="Chocolate" BorderColor="#999999" 
BorderStyle="Solid" NodeSpacing="2px" BorderWidth="2px" 
 ChildNodesPadding="2px" ImageUrl="WebApplication1/images/MenuUp.png" 
Font-Bold="True" />
                  
                    <SelectedNodeStyle BackColor="#2591b0"  BorderColor="#999999" 
   BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px"
                        Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Larger"   Font-Underline="True" 
  ForeColor="Black" ChildNodesPadding="2px"
                        CssClass="SelectedNodeStyle"  />
       
                 <LevelStyles>
        
          <asp:TreeNodeStyle ChildNodesPadding="10" 
            Font-Bold="true" 
            Font-Size="12pt" 
            ForeColor="DarkGreen"/>
          <asp:TreeNodeStyle ChildNodesPadding="5" 
            Font-Bold="true" 
            Font-Size="10pt"/>
          <asp:TreeNodeStyle ChildNodesPadding="5" 
            Font-UnderLine="true" 
            Font-Size="10pt"/>
          <asp:TreeNodeStyle ChildNodesPadding="10" 
            Font-Size="8pt"/>
             
        </LevelStyles>
                       
             </asp:TreeView>
```

it will filled according to database retrieved  the c# code like this :

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode node,SubNode;
  
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ds = data_lnk.xxx(user, "iso", "52");

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                node = new TreeNode();

                node.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["name"].ToString();
                //  node.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node);

                dsSub = data_lnk.yyy(user, "", "52", ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["dep"].ToString());
                if (dsSub.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    for (int j = 0; j < dsSub.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        SubNode = new TreeNode();
                        SubNode.NavigateUrl = dsSub.Tables[0].Rows[j]["path"].ToString();
                       
                        SubNode.Text = dsSub.Tables[0].Rows[j]["file_name"].ToString();
             

                        TreeView1.Nodes[i].ChildNodes.Add(SubNode);
                        if (dsSub.Tables[0].Rows[j]["color"].ToString() == "green")

                        {

                     //Here we should the Node if green in green color 
                        }
           else 
         {
                        //Here color leaf node in red color 
          }


                    }
                }

            }
        }

       
        TreeView1.CollapseAll();
    }
}
```

'''

My problem how to color the background( or  apply any style) in  LeafTreeNode /ParentTreeNode according to code